# Testing sqlite database application on device

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am working on a database application that works fine in the simulator (inserts, updates, deletes all function correctly).  My problem starts when attempting to install/run the application on an iPhone.

On the initial run, the program creates an editable version of the database in the documents directory of the application.  My test fails when the database is not found in the application bundle.  The database has been added to the Resources folder in XCode.

The code to check for an existing version of the database (coupled with several NSLog statements), and to create one if one does not already exist is as follows:

-(NSString *) createWriteableDatabase
{
    BOOL databaseExists;
    NSError *error;

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writeableDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashCard.db"];

NSLog(@"writeableDB = '%@'.", writeableDB);

databaseExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writeableDB];

NSLog(@"databaseExists = %d.", databaseExists);

if (databaseExists)
    return writeableDB;

//--- Writeable version of database does not exist -- copy from bundled software. ---

NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashCard.db"];

NSLog(@"defaultPath = '%@'.", defaultPath);

databaseExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:defaultPath];

NSLog(@"databaseExists = %d.", databaseExists);

databaseExists = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writeableDB error:&error];

if (!databaseExists)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writeable database file: '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    return @"";
}

return writeableDB;
```

}

The messages displayed in the debugger are as follows:

warning: Unable to read symbols for /XCode 3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
2011-06-10 21:12:11.130 FlashEm[3768:707] writeableDB = '/var/mobile/Applications/9DBC50B5-2559-4E6A-BD21-B5B56D9DA18A/Documents/flashCard.db'.
2011-06-10 21:12:11.144 FlashEm[3768:707] databaseExists = 0.
2011-06-10 21:12:11.149 FlashEm[3768:707] defaultPath = '/var/mobile/Applications/9DBC50B5-2559-4E6A-BD21-B5B56D9DA18A/FlashEm.app/flashCard.db'.
2011-06-10 21:12:11.154 FlashEm[3768:707] databaseExists = 0.
2011-06-10 21:12:11.169 FlashEm[3768:707] *** Assertion failure in -[DBAccess createWriteableDatabase], /Users/marathoner1234/Projects/FlashEm/Classes/../DBAccess.m:92
2011-06-10 21:12:11.201 FlashEm[3768:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writeable database file: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory'.'

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me, and I apologize if my question text is not formatted properly -- this is my first time asking a question on this site.

(I looked at two other questions where the same problem was occurring, and checked to see if the same issues they had applied to my situation, but they do not.)

Comment: Can you post the actual name of the database file that is in your bundle?

Comment: Have you checkmarked the copy while you saved the database file in your project.Check that as well.Its not finding the database in the device because its not getting the database.On simulator its working fine as it has the reference there.You can also check for other issues.Thats just my idea

Comment: File name shown in Resources folder is flashcard.db.  File was added after checking 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'.  I've since deleted the file and re-copied it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

your crash report says your database file not found your document directory. This happen only if you not properly install database file inside your resources folder means inside your bundle, so the program on iphone device not able to read your database file.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the database was added to the Resources folder within XCode.  If not, it would not run properly in the Simulator either.

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet, but I found my error: Glaring, bonehead error on my part - if it had been a rattlesnake, it would have bitten me ages ago.  Filename specified in code is flashCard.db (upper-case 'C'); filename in Resources folder is flashcard.db (lower-case 'c').  Changed filename in code, problem solved.

Thank you all who added comments.